# How to update rendered HTML file to reflect changes made in another route (Flask)?

Tags: python, html, flask, caching

I have a Flask application where I have two routes: `close_card()` and `landing()`.

In the `close_card()` route, I am deleting a file based on some submitted form data, and then I want to refresh the `landing()` route to display the updated data.

Here are the simplified versions of the two routes (both are stored as blueprints and imported into the app `__init__` page):

```
from flask import (Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request,
                   session, url_for)
import os
import pandas as pd

bp = Blueprint('projects', __name__, url_prefix='/')

def existing_files_check(directory):
    """ Checks for existing dataframes in the instance/ directory. If
        these exist, then returns the loaded dataframes as a list """
        
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    
    if not files:
        return
    else:
        # Filenames are timestamps so making them negative allows me to control
        # the order in which they are then inserted into a dictionary
        files = [-float(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]) for filename in os.listdir(directory)] 
        ordered_files = sorted(range(len(files)), key=lambda k: files[k])
        all_files = {'len_data':{}, 'numerical_data':{}}
        # Convert each dataframe into a usable dictionary for **contents
        # for the landing page            
        for ix in range(len(ordered_files)):
            df = pd.read_pickle(directory+files[ordered_files[ix]])
            df_dict = df.to_dict(orient='index')
            all_files['numerical_data'][ix] = df_dict[0]
        all_files['len_data'] = len(files)
        return all_files

@bp.route("hub/close_card", methods=["POST"])
def close_card():
    # Receive a timestamp (==filename) from the landing page
    timestamp = request.form.get("stamp")
    print("PROPOSED FILE DELETION:", 'instance/{}.pkl'.format(timestamp))
    # Remove the file from the /instance directory
    os.remove('instance/{}.pkl'.format(timestamp))
    return landing()

@bp.route('hub', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def landing():
    # Get all the files and turn them into a dictionary to be passed to the html page
    files = existing_files_check('instance/')
    return render_template('creation_suite/data_hub.html', contents=files)
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I delete a file in the close_card() route and render the HTML page again in `landing()`, the rendered file (data_hub.html) does not display the updated data.

---

I have already tried the following approaches, but none of them worked:

Using redirect instead of render_template in close_card(): I believe this has the same effect in that it simply points to an existing chached render of the desired html page rather than making a fresh new one.

Adding cache control headers to the response: I tried adding headers like 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' in the before_request function, but it didn't appear to do anything at all.

Inserting a `location.reload(true)` js statement in the HTML script. This caused a refresh loop but maybe a mix of this and some unique cache parameters can force a single refresh on rendering the HTMl page.

Adding a client-side (in the HTML) reload statement with a user defined delay, to give the backend time to complete the file deletion in the background:

```
<script>
// Reload the page after a delay to ensure the deletion process is completed
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, 10);  // Adjust the delay (in milliseconds) as needed
</script>
```

this approach does work but it seems to be a very clunky method that won't work in 100% of cases.

I realise that in reality you'd probably want to update the data on the backend using post requests, and sort out the front end information using HTML and js only. However I'm really new to this so I thought I'd try to get this workflow working first and I'm curious to know if it can be done. (I also realise it's a clunky and bizarre way of storing data on the backend and that I should be using things like sqlite instead; but again, I'm new to this and would like to solve this specific problem before evolving to a more efficient database handling style with flask).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!